# Strong Inductive proof for inequality using Fibonacci sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, induction, proof-explanation, fibonacci-numbers

I am trying to prove that $F_n \geq 4 * F_{(n - 3)}$ using the Fibonacci sequence, I think it the proof requires strong induction but I am unsure of how to apply it.

My work so far:

Define the Fibonacci numbers by:

\begin{align*}
 F_0 &= 0 \\
 F_1 &= 1 \\
 F_n &= F_{(n-1)} + F_{(n-2)} \forall n \geq 2
\end{align*}

1. Prove by induction that $F_n \geq 4 * F_{(n - 3)}$

   Base case: $n = 5$

   \begin{align*}
     F_5 &\geq 4 * F_{(5 - 3)} \\
     F_5 &\geq 4 * F_{(2)} \\
     F_5 &\geq 4 * 1 \\
     5 &\geq 4
    \end{align*}

   Suppose true for some $n = k$
   \begin{equation}
     F_k \geq 4 * F_{(k - 3)}
    \end{equation}
   Inductive step: Consider case $n = k + 1$

   \begin{align*}
     F_{(k + 1)} &\geq 4 * F_{(k + 1 - 3)} \\
     F_{(k + 1)} &\geq 4 * F_{(k - 2)} 
    \end{align*}

The $F_{(k - 2)}$ makes me think the of the Fibonacci definition and that it should be possible if I use $n = 5, 6$ in the base case. However I am not sure what the next step should be so I can go further.

EDIT:

So thanks to Mohammad Riazi-Kermani I was able to go further. Since the Fibonacci sequence is defined as a recurrence relation, I can use the preceding terms to manipulate the expression. i.e.
\begin{align*}
    F_0 &= 0 \\
    F_1 &= 1 \\
    F_2 &= F_1 + F_0 \\
    F_3 &= F_2 + F_1 \\
    F_4 &= F_3 + F_2 \\
    \text etc.
\end{align*}

So following the pattern
\begin{align*}\\
 F_n &= F_{(n-1)} + F_{(n-2)}\\
 F_{(n-1)} &= F_{((n-1)-1)} + F_{((n-1)-2)}\\
           &= F_{(n-2)} + F_{(n-3)}\\
 F_{(n-2)} &= F_{((n-2)-1)} + F_{((n-2)-2)}\\
           &= F_{(n-3)} + F_{(n-4)}\\
 F_n &= F_{(n-2)} + F_{(n-3)} + F_{(n-3)} + F_{(n-4)}
\end{align*}

Now I have $F_n = 3*F_{(n-3)} + 2*F_{(n-4)}$ which allows me to get to the hint pointed out by Theo Bendit.

\begin{align*}
  3*F_{(n-3)} + 2*F_{(n-4)} &\geq 4*F_{(n-3)}\\
                2*F_{(n-4)} &\geq F_{(n-3)}
 \end{align*}

But what does this mean since I did not have to do the inductive step?

EDIT 2:

It seems I am confusing the inductive hypothesis (assuming $P(k)$) with $P(k + 1)$.

So true for all $n \geq 5$ by principle of mathematical induction. Q.E.D.

Comment: Hint: by playing around with the recurrence relation, you can show $F_n = 3F_{n-3} + 2F_{n-4}$. So, if you can show $2F{n-4} \ge F_{n-3}$, then you're done. If you play around further, you can show that this is equivalent to the Fibonacci sequence increasing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$F_n=F_{n-1}+F_{n-2}$$

$$=F_{n-2}+F_{n-3}+F_{n-3}+F_{n-4}$$

$$=3F_{n-3}+2F_{n-4} \ge 3F_{n-3}+F_{n-4}+F_{n-5}$$

$$=4F_{n-3}$$

Comment: So you can increase the sequence based on the recursive definition of the Fibonacci sequence. On the second line I assume that’s what you did by letting $n = n - 1$, is that fair? Is a let statement needed?

Comment: Yes, we just use the recursive relation to expand $F_n$